# Webpack - how to determine output style of CSS file?

Tags: css, webpack, sass

When using Gulp to convert Sass to CSS, I can choose output style of the CSS file between: nested, expanded, compact and compressed. Do I have the same opportunity using Webpack? If yes, can you show me how to configurate Webpack to achieve my goal?

Below is my current webpack.config.js - it converts sass to css, translate ES6 to ES5 and it works perfectly:

```
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./js/app.js",
        "./scss/main.scss"
    ],
    output: {
        filename: "./js/out.js"
    },
    watch: true,
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ["es2015"]
                }
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
                    use: ["css-loader?-url", "sass-loader?-url"]
                })
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "./css/main.css",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `sass-loader`, which uses `node-sass` under the hood. The [readme](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) says that you can pass options directly to `node-sass` by specifying an `options` property. You can pass in the `outputStyle` setting this way. It would look like this:

```
{
    test: /.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
        use: [{
            loader: 'css-loader'
        }, {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
            }
        }]
    })
}
```

Comment: That ticked solution won't work with upgraded webpack and sass-loader. I have added an answer for those that might also be struggling with updates

Answer (score 1):

@Arnelle Balane
That ticked solution won't work with upgraded webpack and sass-loader.

This is the latest working model using:

- "webpack": "^4.44.1",
- "sass-loader": "~9.0.3",

```js
{
    test: /.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallbackLoader: "style-loader",
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader'
          }, 
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
              }
            }
          }
        ]
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE Wepback 5: ExtractTextplugin is now replace to MiniCSSExtraPlugin.

```
     use: [
        
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        { 
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
            sassOptions: {
              outputStyle: "expanded",
            },
          }
        },

      ]
```